# How to get first and last date of a given week number and year?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I'm new into ios programming and desperately trying to get the first and last date of a give week with referenced year.

I tried to build a method but do get weird dates.

```
+ (NSArray*)getStartDateOfWeek : (NSInteger)weekNumber withYear:(NSInteger)year {
    NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    // Week Start Date

    NSCalendar *gregorianStart = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *componentsStart = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];


    [componentsStart setWeekOfYear:weekNumber];
    [componentsStart setYear:year];

    int startDayOfWeek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[gregorianStart dateFromComponents:componentsStart]] weekday];
    [componentsStart setDay:([componentsStart day] - ((startDayOfWeek) - 2))];

    NSDate *beginningOfWeek = [gregorianStart dateFromComponents:componentsStart];

    // Week End Date

    NSCalendar *gregorianEnd = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDateComponents *componentsEnd = [[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [componentsStart setWeekOfYear:weekNumber];
    [componentsStart setYear:year];

    int endDayOfWeek = [[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:[gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd]] weekday];

    [componentsEnd setDay:([componentsEnd day]+ (7 - endDayOfWeek) + 1)]; // for end day of the week

    NSDate *endOfWeek = [gregorianEnd dateFromComponents:componentsEnd];

    [result insertObject:beginningOfWeek atIndex:0];
    [result insertObject:endOfWeek atIndex:1];

    return result;
}
```

Any help is thankfully appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want the Sunday (first day) and Saturday (last day) of a given week, this code will do what you want (for clarity I have created two methods, but you could combine them back in to one) -

```
+ (NSDate *)firstDayOfWeek:(NSInteger)weekNumber inYear:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSDateComponents *comps=[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [comps setWeekday:1];                                   //Change this to 2 if you want Monday rather than Sunday
    [comps setWeekOfYear:weekNumber];

    [comps setYear:year];
    [comps setYearForWeekOfYear:year];

    NSCalendar *cal=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *newDate=[cal dateFromComponents:comps];

    return newDate;

}

+ (NSDate *)lastDayOfWeek:(NSInteger)weekNumber inYear:(NSInteger)year
{
    NSDateComponents *comps=[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
    [comps setWeekday:7];                                  //Change this to 6 if you want Friday rather than Saturday
    [comps setWeekOfYear:weekNumber];

    [comps setYear:year];
    [comps setYearForWeekOfYear:year];

    NSCalendar *cal=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

    NSDate *newDate=[cal dateFromComponents:comps];

    return newDate;

}
```

One important point is the `[comps setYearForWeekOfYear:year];` - otherwise you may get unexpected results for week 1 - By default you will get the "last" week 1 in the year, which is also week 1 of the following year, so you end up a year later than you expected.

If you wanted to combine the two into one method, I would use an `NSDictionary` rather than an `NSArray` -

```
 +(NSDictionary *)firstAndLastDayOfWeek:(NSInteger)weekNumber inYear:(NSInteger)year
    {
        NSDateComponents *comps=[[NSDateComponents alloc]init];
        [comps setWeekday:1];
        [comps setWeekOfYear:weekNumber];

        [comps setYear:year];
        [comps setYearForWeekOfYear:year];

        NSCalendar *cal=[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];

        NSDate *firstDay=[cal dateFromComponents:comps];

        [comps setWeekday:7];

        NSDate *lastDay=[cal dateFromComponents:comps];

        return @{@"firstDay":firstDay,@"lastDay":lastDay};

    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. NSDate + NSCalendar are the confusing part of objective-c. It works...